# I am new to IPFS. Is there any need for checking where the IPFS file originates from for security purposes?

Tags: ipfs

I want to identify the ipfs source node. Is it necessary to do that in IPFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't find where a file comes from on IPFS. However, when you add a file to IPFS through your IPFS node like this:

```
$ ipfs add ~/helloworld.txt 
added QmWATWQ7fVPP2EFGu71UkfnqhYXDYH566qy47CnJDgvs8u helloworld.txt
```

The file is automatically pinned on your node, it means it is permanently stored at least until unpinned. A non-pinned file is removed from the node after a certain amount of time (like a cache).

Any nodes can decide to also pin a content on IPFS (think replication):

```
$ ipfs pin add QmWATWQ7fVPP2EFGu71UkfnqhYXDYH566qy47CnJDgvs8u
pinned QmWATWQ7fVPP2EFGu71UkfnqhYXDYH566qy47CnJDgvs8u recursively
```

Then it is possible to discover all nodes (identifier of the node) that have pinned this content on the network using the following command:

```
$ ipfs dht findprovs QmWATWQ7fVPP2EFGu71UkfnqhYXDYH566qy47CnJDgvs8u
QmQVricDKJeFWFvvyD3E7WwwRBkum54jmjdj5yv3NpdqAs
QmTGfEbUM1xz5Po6sVNj2KcMP6HjmrivRB9PLE13GxFZFG
QmV1eTGvh9vqT9vFzf593XAmTDroHZtZEuiUXBaJ53z6b5
QmV2ZonzMpvX3DfFi35uT3Frb4e4L8cATQrb4ZSM3jt3ZE
QmXM22ePEJMbJ1HhZR5khxaHK2PFfWM9gb7UsdHxSJEydP
QmaeUxeAK3N5fyU5o5W8eFeHGy7SUgcxfscewNNGgFak8L
Qmc2D7Wwuy8sGV19eAWg9tAtLUnSkEazkgjiYxP8NMD6k7
QmfLu1CARPvzSFvSrk1cc5yueT3DAvdckfdcDGsVgeJiH6
QmaJBMtVJhYnZzikiJqoWi4rDErVNnE6Y7xGLqAsVA2Z12
QmPrYfg99FYVzJ47eUBGde3STUDHoH1iQTPRfeo98K8Rzi
QmQ6qTyjnBETj3uRxXZb7xFFqqY1hpDwRSfWpbZNmzSk5B
QmSNXv7s6XsBHnyJgnZNApDC1yccjoR2Af6zmzqViNKS8z
QmT1cwtvuKknEaaRRr1oz5Up81Y9fhNQnwtHJ4wa319Q3E
QmUjqjKVmWiXJp9HxBJF7Z9Qke5ruNd6BGxwMGxgyM6Ry9
QmX15kSQGh5KgzQ5Qu2j39Yr1DRXLUQ7bUPAgRrCxbe2KQ
QmYxoZmhx5kiAd8MK5ZgMF2Co2GpH2xXWSm8T6JPnrwzUt
Qma8h47ZCpd575DkbTgtytZaBrMDGroGd6WgXU22sPQWWv
```

Notes:

- I think the command output has a limit of 20 items.
- Those aren't file hash but node ID

So in conclusion you can't find where a file is originated but you can at least know where its stored.